# Launching vbs file on startup

Tags: windows-10, boot, vbscript

I'm trying to start a vbs file when I turn the computer on. So far I've put the file into the start up file and created a task with task scheduler that starts the program upon start up. Neither have worked. The vbs file is calling a bat file that is calling a python program. I am trying to run the program without the console popping up. Double clicking the vbs file does exactly what I want it to do. So I need help starting the vbs file on start up or hiding the console and using the bat file on start up.

Also, putting the bat file in the start up folder executes fine, I just don't want the console to show

Comment: I don't know anout VBS files, but if it is executable, try putting it into the regsitry, in the `run` hive. See  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706267/launch-vbs-script-after-pc-startup    I tried following this guide, however it still didn't run on startup for me

Comment: Execute .vbs files by running `cscript.exe` with the name of the .vbs file as a parameter. I.e. the command run would be something like `C:\windows\system32\cscript.exe myscript.vbs`. If that doesn’t work post both your .vbs script and batch file as it is not necessary to have a vbs call a bat to call a python script. The bat file is not needed and the functionality can be put in the vbs.

Comment: Just FYI: My edit was incorporating a comment of the author into the question. Because my edit was disapproved, the information is lost. This error has been caused by sloppy reviews.

Comment: There is not really a whole lot different between using startup or manually clicking but one point is relative paths and workingdirs. Do you use relative paths especially in the vbs file?